# Adding speedbumps to some page links with javascript, confirm doesn't redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, redirect

I'm developing a site in vs2012, using ASP and VB backend, CSS and JavaScript.  Long story short, if a link takes the user off our site, it needs to have one of those disclaimer speedbumps saying we're not responsible blah blah.  I do this with the following code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var anchors = $("a").get();
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        var anchor_element = anchors[i];
        var url = anchor_element.attributes[0].nodeValue;
        if ((url.indexOf('.com') != -1) || (url.indexOf('ForwardProcessing') != -1)) {
            anchor_element.onclick = function () {
                return window.confirm('The link you selected will take you to a third party website...\r\rClick <CANCEL> if you would like to stay.');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So this accurately finds the links I'm looking for, and attaches the speed bump just fine (only in IE, but I'll explain more on that in a minute).  But at run time, then, when you click ok, I get the mouse pointer turning into a hand with an exclamation point, and the page doesn't change.  Obviously there is some error occurring in the JavaScript, but I can't find any good place in the code to put a break point to see what error might be happening.

Which leads to the second problem... this only seems to work in IE.  I tried using firefox/firebug to look at the js, and the speedbump never occurs, the user goes straight on to the next page... which tells me there's *definitely* something wrong, but even less information.  Any JavaScript experts out there see anything?  I'm still pretty new to js, and after googling it for a day, haven't found anything...

UPDATE:  The issue seems to be pop up related?  In the html, I use target = _blank to open the link in a new tab... taking this out resolves the issue, but I'd like to use the new tab... is there a conflict in this?

Comment: what you have works for me in Chrome, FireFox, and IE11: http://jsfiddle.net/N79sW/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following `onclick` line to:

```
anchor_element.onclick = "return window.confirm('The link you selected will take you to a third party website...\r\rClick <CANCEL> if you would like to stay.');";
```

And fix up the bracketing of course.   I haven't tested it, but thought you could faster than I could setting up a test scenario.  If it doesn't work let me know.

**EDIT:** Just tested your original change and my change and both work fine so my answer is not a solution... can you post what your error is?  I don't get one except when it redirects to www.google.com I get a error on the google page but my other 3 test redirect pages work fine.

Here is my test code...

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a><br />
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com" target="_blank">Microsoft</a><br />
<a href="http://www.apple.com">Apple</a><br />
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a><br />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var anchors = $("a").get();

        for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
            var anchor_element = anchors[i];
            var url = anchor_element.attributes[0].nodeValue;
            if ((url.indexOf('.com') != -1) || (url.indexOf('ForwardProcessing') != -1)) {
                anchor_element.onclick = "return window.confirm('The link you selected will take you to a third party website...\r\rClick <CANCEL> if you would like to stay.');";                    
            }
        }
    });
```

Nothing else in the page and it works.

**EDIT 2:**  I tested using IE11 with pop up blocker on and do not experience any issue. Sites open in a new tab with no issue. Pop up blocker was set to 'medium'.

Comment: If I do that, then the speed bumps all pop up on the page load, and then don't occur when I click on the link :/

Comment: Are you sure you are posting the EXACT code?  I will post my test code for you to see.

Comment: I copy and pasted it directly, and the only edit I made was replacing the wording in the speedbump which included our company name.

Comment: @Jon There has to be something else going on... put my code in a blank HTML page and you will see that it works. (Make sure you have the jquery references of course too)

Comment: The error actually seems to be a pop up blocker issue?  I can get around it if I'm not using "target= _blank" in the actual link... does this affect the javascript?

Comment: @Jon is the link trying to do a pop up in a new window?  If so you could look for those links and strip off the 'pop up' part and make it just redirect as normal from the current page.  Does it work fine for links that don't 'pop up'?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem.  Is there a conflict when you try and add a speed bump to a new tab?  I was hoping to include both features...

Comment: @Jon not sure how you are going to get around that issue since that is controlled by the browser... if you could get around it, it would pretty much defeat the purpose of the pop up blocker ;)  I think I have given you at least an option you could use of stripping out the popup that should help.

Comment: @Jon I tested using IE11 with pop up blocker on and do not experience any issue.  Sites open in a new tab with no issue.  Pop up blocker was set to 'medium'.

Comment: hmm. yeah, ok, maybe the pop up blocker wasn't correct.  Seems to be purely related to the target = _blank :/

Comment: @Jon does my simple example work for you?  It has the `target="_blank"` in the links and works fine for me. There has to be more going on...  Not sure how much more help I can be.

Comment: @Jon Sorry I can't really help any further as I have posted a working example.  There is nothing else for me to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The code, in the end, had 2 issues.
The first is that I needed to use anchor_element.href -> IE recognized attributes[0] as href, but if firefox, this was a CSS value.  specifying WHICH attribute solved this.

The reason it wasn't working in IE, where there was no follow through with the link post-confirmation is a bit embarrassing.  I had popup blocker turned off in IE... but not in my google toolbar.  :/

But I only got here because other's confirmed it worked for them.  Thanks to all!